# Transfer A Row Or Multiple Row From Listview To DataGridview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, datagridview

Is it possible to transfer a row or multiple rows from listview to datagrdiview?. If yes than provide some code.

Suppose Listview1 having 7 columns and multiple rows where as  the datagridview1 also having 7 columns.

If I wants to move a selected rows of listview1 with 7 columns's rows to datagridview than how to do?.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  Assume you have a Winform with a ListView named listView1 and a DataGridView with no columns named dataGridView1 run this:

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("SelectedItemCol", "Selected Items");
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.SelectedItems) {
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(item.Text);
}
```

Comment: I think the point is that mahesh has to it on his own.
There is no mechanism which transfers the items atomatically.

Comment: @Boas Enkler, Are sure that there is no real mechanism to transfer the selected items from listview to dgv?

Comment: I don'nt now any.

The only solution i know is to change the architecture.
For example if you have a MVVM application, and both contorls are bound to an datasource you coud just move the entity from one datasource to the other.

Havign a databinding, then your contorls will update this change by themselves. But thats an architectural not an technical solution

Comment: @mahesh I'm not sure what you're looking for in a 'real mechanism.'  Any solution would require an elaboration on what I've shown (which is simplistic but works).  The data binding possibilities in the Winform ListView are limited, perhaps you can use a different control.